# JavaFX Separate Perspective View on a 3D Chess Field

Tags: 3d, javafx, perspectivecamera

I got following game-window:
http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3598/b48lqpur_png.htm (Sorry cant post img here)

The red Box is a VBox (or an other Container, i cant decide yet).
And i wanna set a 3D perspective Chessfield instead of the star.
But if i load the Framework (like the Java-Tutorial MoleculeSampleApp) in to the Container, i get 4 results:

- The first: i see the 3D chessfield but all outside my Container
  rotates with the Chessfield.
- The second: i see no chessfield (but my console-outputs says all
  steps of creating chessfield are correctly done)
- The third: i see one black Box without any perspective.
- The last: i only see the Framework of the Chessfield

My sorcecode is:

```
Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(
                createScene(loadPane(ContentManager.DEFAULT_SCREEN_FXML, ContentManager.GAME_SCREEN_FXML))
        );
        FieldLayerController flc = new FieldLayerController();
        flc.setFieldSize(6);
        flc.buildField();
        flc.buildScene();
        flc.buildCamera();
        Scene scene = new Scene(flc.root, 1024, 768, true);
        flc.handleKeyboard(scene, (Node)flc.world);
        flc.handleMouse(scene, (Node)flc.world);
        Node node = stage.getScene().lookup("#game_box");
        ((VBox)node).getChildren().add(flc.root);
    stage.show();
```

This Code produce the Window you see on the picture.

Is it possible to get a perspective view only in one Container?

I hope I could describe my problem understandable.
(like [JavaFX 3D - How to set different cameras for Group with 3D object and SubScene with UI Controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19210391/javafx-3d-how-to-set-different-cameras-for-group-with-3d-object-and-subscene-w))

Answer (score 4):

Check out our project .. [F(X)yz](https://github.com/Birdasaur/FXyz)   it's a JavaFX 3D library.. There is a CameraView class and a Cutaway class (CameraView wrapped in a dragable frame) that may do as you are looking for. Clone the project and run the CameraViewTest. Both the main scene, and cameraView have mouse handlers for movement so play around.. Another example of it is in the BillboardBehaviorTest class.

Hope this helps!